# A problem on compact space

Tags: general-topology, compactness

Given $X$  a compact space and $Y$ a metric space. $f$ and $g$ are continuous mappings from $X$ to $Y$. Does the set $A=\{(f(x),g(x))|x\in X\}$ need to be a compact set in $Y\times Y$?

Comment: Hint: $A = (f \times g)(\Delta_X)$, where $\Delta_X = \{(x,x) : x \in X\}$.

Comment: @user10354138 Thanks. It’s corrected now.

Answer (score 1):

$\textit{(There is actually no issue, see edit below)}$

I think there is a little issue with working with the 'diagonal' $D = \{(x,x): x \in X$}, as is done in the other answer and the comments. For this argument to be sound I think you need the diagonal to be closed (hence compact as a subset of a compact space), but the diagonal is only closed in Hausdorff spaces, which is not given for $X$. But I think one can proceed as follows:

Let $h:X \to Y \times Y, x \mapsto (f(x),g(x))$. This function is continuous since $f$ and $g$ are continuous. Now we have

$$ h(X) = \{h(x) : x \in X\} = \{(f(x), g(x)): x \in X \} = A $$

Since $X$ is compact and $h$ is continuous, $A$ is also compact as the image of a compact set under a continuous function.

Edit: As Jihai Zhu pointed out in the comment, there is actually no problem with the approach using the diagonal, since the diagonal is compact when $X$ is. No need to argue with closed sets.

Comment: It’s a good approach. $D$ is indeed compact in $X\times X$(while $D$ is not always closed).

Comment: You are right, I think I did some overthinking, D is indeed compact when X is. I'll edit my post! Thanks!